# how to destroy a layout before we rebuild it Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt5

I have a little problem displaying my layouts. I have an application that contains a GridLayout, HBoxLayout, and VBoxLayout.

The HBoxLayout contains: a button and line edit
The GridLayout contains: progbars (1-99)

The HBoxLayout and the GridLayout are put in a VBoxLayout

My problem is when I click, The grid layout appears on the HBoxLayout. It's like the HBoxLayout wasn't a part of the VBoxLayout. So, even when I destroy the layout and create it again, I still have the same problem. 
An image is displayed below to better understand my problem.

[image]

[image]

code: window.cpp

```
    Window::Window(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent){
    label = NULL;
    progressbar = NULL;
    workerThread = NULL;
    m_counter = NULL;

    layout = new QHBoxLayout(NULL);
    lineEdit = new QLineEdit(NULL);
    m_button = new QPushButton("click", NULL);
    time= new QTimer(this);

    lineEdit-> setInputMask("00");;
    //lineEdit->setGeometry(400,10,160,30);
    lineEdit->setPlaceholderText("N between 1 & 99");

    // Create and position the button
    // m_button->setGeometry(100, 10, 150, 30);

    QIcon icon("/home/ca/Downloads/chauvin.png");
    m_button->setIcon(icon);
    m_button->setIconSize(QSize(100, 30));
    m_button->setToolTip("this is a beautifull button ");

    //layout = new QFormLayout;
    layout->addWidget(m_button);
    layout->addWidget(lineEdit);
    setLayout( layout );

    // showTime();
    time->start(1000);
    setWindowTitle(tr("Digital Clock"));


    // NEW : Do the connection
    connect(m_button, &QPushButton::pressed, this , &Window::slotButtonPressed);}

void Window::slotButtonPressed(){
     layoutgrid = new QGridLayout(NULL);
     m_button->setEnabled(true);
     QString contenu = lineEdit->text();
     int i_contenunumber= contenu.toInt(0,10);
     m_counter= new int[i_contenunumber];
     memset( m_counter, 0, i_contenunumber );
     label = new QLabel*[ i_contenunumber ];
     progressbar = new QProgressBar*[ i_contenunumber ];
     workerThread= new mythread*[ i_contenunumber ];

     int x= 0;
     int y= -1;
     int i=0;
     m_button->setText("Checked");

     for(i=0;i< i_contenunumber ;i++)
     {
        if (i%5==0)
        {
            x=0;
            y++;
        }


     int i_Randomvalue = rand() % 500 + 100;

        //        label[i] = new QLabel(NULL);
        //        //label[i]->setGeometry(100*x*1.7, 80+(50*y), 160, 30);
        //        label[i]->setText("Tread" + QString::number(i_Randomvalue));
        //        label[i]->setVisible(true);

        progressbar[i] = new QProgressBar(NULL);
        progressbar[i]->setRange(0, 100);
        progressbar[i]->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
        //progressbar[i]->setGeometry(100*x*1.7,60+(50*y),150,30);
        progressbar[i]->setValue(0);
        progressbar[i]->setVisible(true);
        layoutgrid->addWidget(progressbar[i],y,x);
        setLayout(layoutgrid);

        workerThread[i] = new mythread(i_Randomvalue, i);

        connect(workerThread[i], &mythread::signalemit, this, &Window::barprogress);enter code here
        connect(workerThread[i], &mythread::signalFinThread, this, &Window::findethread);

        workerThread[i] ->start();

        x++;

        m_counter[i]=0;
    }
    //    Window::setFixedSize(1000,120+(50*y-1));

      removeLayout();

      layoutvbox = new QVBoxLayout(NULL);
      layoutvbox->addLayout(layout);
      layoutvbox->addLayout(layoutgrid);
      setLayout(layoutvbox);
      adjustSize();

}



void Window::removeLayout ( void )
{
    QLayout* po_l_layout = QWidget::layout ();
    if (po_l_layout != 0)
    {
        QLayoutItem *item;
        while ((item = po_l_layout->takeAt(0)) != 0)
            po_l_layout->removeItem (item);
        delete po_l_layout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

delete layout will not work here because it will not delete all the containing widgets

Instead just create a new widget that contains the layout

```
m_widget = new QWidget();
QGridLayout *outerLayout = new QGridLayout(m_widget);
m_layout->addWidget(m_widget);
this->setLayout(m_layout);
```

to remove and rebuild just delete the widget

```
delete m_widget
```

deleting a widget deletes all sub layouts and widgets contained by the widget

Answer (score 0):

Once the layout of your widget is set, you can not change it unless you remove the old layout.  My suggestion is to delete the old layout

```
//remove all of layouts widgets here
delete layout
```

Then create the QVBoxLayout and call `setLayout(layoutvbox)`

If you wish to switch back and forth, just recreate/delete when needed.

Comment: This isn't quite true -- you can modify the layout at any time (my programs do it routinely).  One limitation I have come across is that once you add a widget to a row or column of a QGridLayout, the number-of-rows (or number-of-columns) in the QGridLayout is expanded to accomodate that widget, and there doesn't seem to be any way to reduce the number of rows/columns again (even if you later delete the widget)

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner Can you change layouts once a layout is set though?  I know you can edit the layout (add widgets/remove widgets).  But can you set the layout to a completely different layout without first removing/deleting it?  Also interesting about the grid layout, I didn't know that was an interaction.